# MediaPlayer playing files on AVD, on PDA throwing errors

Tags: android, android-emulator, media-player, android-virtual-device

This is my method in service for playing files, on AVD everything works fine, no errors, when I click the control on PDA I get these LogCat events: http://pastebay.com/125483. I have no clue what is happening. Please advise.

```
public void playAudio (int playAudio) { 

    player = MediaPlayer.create(this, playAudio);

    try {           
        if (player != null) { 
            player.stop();          
            }
        player.prepare();
        player.start();

    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

        } finally {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, the problem was I called prepare(); after MediaPlayer.create since it prepares the MediaPlayer already.